# Is typing date as string faster than using CURDATE()

Tags: mysql, date, optimization

I'm writing a mysql query that finds all the records created in the last 90 days.  Does it make any difference in terms of speed to use:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users 
WHERE created_at > '2016-06-16'
```

compared to:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE created_at > date_sub(curdate(), interval 90 day)
```

Is there another way that would be even faster?

Comment: both would evaluate to a constant value, so you pay any conversion/translation overhead ONCE when the query starts. whatever minor differences in cpu time between having a hardcoded value and calculating that same value will be MASSIVELY dwarfed by the cost of running the rest of the query.

Comment: I like `>= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY` -- clear, not too verbose, and sufficiently efficient.